# Best practice to provide list of required in autofac based nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget, autofac

I created an NuGet Package, I want to use in a couple of autofac based projects. This is no problem because I know what classes are needed and how to register them in depended projects.

But, if I want to offer this module to foreign developer what is the best practice to "document" what object they have to register?

Example:
In some case I need a Repository to access data from a datasource.

```
using(var childScope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifeTimeScope())
   childScope.Resolve<IAmARepositoryInterface>().Insert(test);
```

But a stranger has not a clue until an exceptions was thrown because of a missing registration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a package with Autofac registrations. Put them in a module etc. Then have that package explain how to register. Look at MVCSiteMapProvider as example https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/nuget/mvcsitemapprovider.di.modules .

If you want to support more DI containers have one package per supported container